# Warning: mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: php

my code-

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
```

but it throws warning-
**Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\xampp\htdocs\pics\confirm_login_credentials.php on line 3**

and
**Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\xampp\htdocs\pics\confirm_login_credentials.php on line 3**

Answer (score 5):

[`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) requires an established link to the database to distinguish the actually used character encoding:

> **Note:** A MySQL connection is required before using **mysql_real_escape_string()** otherwise an error of level **E_WARNING** is generated, and **FALSE** is returned. If *link_identifier* isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

It seems that you don’t have that when calling `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: <?php
require 'database.php';
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$q = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_name = '$username' AND password = '$password'";

$result = $mysqli->query($q) or die(mysqli_error());

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
 setcookie('authorized', 1, 0);
 header("Location: index.php");
} else {
 header("Location: login.php"); 
}


?>

Comment: @amanda: MySQL and MySQLi are two different things. Try `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `$mysqli->real_escape_string` instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3120893.htm

You need the database link before anything else.

> ```
> mysql_real_escape_string() takes a connection handler and escapes the
> ```
>
> string according to the current
>   character set. Although depreciated,
>   mysql_escape_string [us3.php.net]
>   doesn't need a connection